# Will be server download each one image in while?

Tags: php, image, while-loop, download

I want to ask if I give image into while loop and he displays for example 10 times. Will be server download each one? or just one ?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you wonder if you display the same image 10 times on a page, will the browser download the same image 10 times? If this is the question then no it will only download one image if they all are the same.

Comment: That is what i mean. Thank you.

Comment: You can easily test this by using a browser extension like for instance firebug for firefox or perhaps the develop tools for chrome. You then click the `Net` or perhaps `Network` tab and reload the page to see all resources that is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first fetch of the image, the remaining 9 will be served from the browser cache, so no. It will only download the image once.